# Why `SYS.odcivarchar2list` not working with `PIPELINED` function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When i try to compile the below code i get the error:

> [Error] PLS-00382 (15: 17): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_pipe
   RETURN SYS.odcivarchar2list
   PIPELINED
AS
   CURSOR cEmploee
   IS
      SELECT first_name FROM employee;

 BEGIN
   FOR i IN cEmploee
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.first_name);
       PIPE ROW (sys.odcivarchar2list (i.first_name));
      EXIT WHEN cEmploee%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END;
/
```

Can anyone explain if `SYS.odcivarchar2list` works with PIPELINED function or not. Let me know how to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: PIPE ROW expects a record type, while `sys.odcivarchar2list` is a table type (a table of rows of some other type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the type of 'var' should be varchar2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_pipe
   RETURN SYS.odcivarchar2list
   PIPELINED
AS
   CURSOR cEmploee
   IS
      SELECT first_name FROM employee;

   var   employee.first_name%type;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN cEmploee
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.first_name);
      var := i.first_name;
      PIPE ROW (var);
      EXIT WHEN cEmploee%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END;
/

select * from table(test_pipe)
```

Comment: But why its not working with `SYS.odcivarchar2list` . I know using `varcahr2` it should work. Ok i edit my question for better understanding.

Comment: You're not returning the list @XING. You're returning data row-by-row, as a VARCHAR2, which Oracle knows how to translate into ODCIVARCHAR2LIST for callers of the function.

Comment: @Ben. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ben's right, this is how pipelined functions work: you return one element of a colledtion (e.g.: an instance of an object type or a varchat2) at a time, not a record-set. By the way, if you put some logging into the function (dbms_output may not be the best for this purpose), you can see that the function gets called as the client fetches data. Not executed once to get the whole result set.